# Basic but proper use of beforeEach() or afterEach() with mocha.js and chai.js

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I want to use mocha/chai to test code related to binary search trees. Here, I am testing the public `insert` method. I want to use `beforeEach()` and/or `afterEach()` hooks to reset the test environment prior to each `it()` statement so that I don't have to completely repeat the basics. However, I keep getting various errors.

Spec

```
describe("BinarySearchTree insert function", function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    var binarySearchTree = new BinarySearchTree();
    binarySearchTree.insert(5);
  });

  it("creates a root node with value equal to the first inserted value", function () {
    expect(binarySearchTree.root.value).to.equal(5);
  });

  it("has a size equal to the amount of inserted values", function () {
    binarySearchTree.insert(3);
    expect(binarySearchTree.size).to.equal(2);
  });

  it("returns an error for non-unique values", function () {
    binarySearchTree.insert(3);
    expect(binarySearchTree.insert(3)).to.throw(String);
  });

  it("if inserted value is larger than current node, make or descend to rightChild", function () {
    binarySearchTree.insert(3);
    binarySearchTree.insert(10);
    binarySearchTree.insert(7);
    expect(binarySearchTree.root.rightChild.value).to.equal(10);
  });

});
```

Error: `ReferenceError: binarySearchTree is not defined`

In truth, I expected errors before there is no `afterEach()` resetting the test environment, not because `binarySearchTree` is not defined. I'd like to accomplish this, if at all possible, with only Mocha and Chai (and not other packages like Sinon, etc).

Tested Code

```
exports.Node = Node;

function Node(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.leftChild = null;
  this.rightChild = null;
}

exports.BinarySearchTree = BinarySearchTree;

function BinarySearchTree() {
  this.root = null;
  this.size = 0;
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.insert = function(value) {
  // 1) when root node is already instantiated
  if (this.root === null) {
    // tree is empty
    this.root = new Node(value);
    this.size++;
  } else {
  // 2) nodes are already inserted
    var findAndInsert = function (currentNode) {
      if (value === currentNode.value) {
        throw new Error('must be a unique value');
      }
      // base case
      if (value > currentNode.value) {
        // belongs in rightChild
        if (currentNode.rightChild === null) {
          currentNode.rightChild = new Node(value);
        } else {
          findAndInsert(currentNode.rightChild);
        }
      } else if (value < currentNode.value) {
        // belongs in leftChild
        if (currentNode.leftChild === null) {
          currentNode.leftChild = new Node(value);
        } else {
          findAndInsert(currentNode.leftChild);
        }
      }
    };
    findAndInsert(this.root);
    this.size++;
  }
};
```

Bonus question... I'm not sure if I am properly testing for the thrown error (when a non-unique value is inserted)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is undefined because it is not in test function scope. Define it one step before in describe scope. For reference, look at the Angular docs. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

```
describe("BinarySearchTree insert function", function() {
  var binarySearchTree;
  beforeEach(function() {
    binarySearchTree = new BinarySearchTree();
    binarySearchTree.insert(5);
  });

  it("creates a root node with value equal to the first inserted value", function () {
    expect(binarySearchTree.root.value).to.equal(5);
  });

  it("has a size equal to the amount of inserted values", function () {
    binarySearchTree.insert(3);
    expect(binarySearchTree.size).to.equal(2);
  });

  it("returns an error for non-unique values", function () {
    binarySearchTree.insert(3);
    expect(binarySearchTree.insert(3)).to.throw(String);
  });

  it("if inserted value is larger than current node, make or descend to rightChild", function () {
    binarySearchTree.insert(3);
    binarySearchTree.insert(10);
    binarySearchTree.insert(7);
    expect(binarySearchTree.root.rightChild.value).to.equal(10);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, Zohaib. And thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting `binarySearchTree` is `undefined` is explained already.

I would like to talk about `beforeEach` and `afterEach` functions.

In `beforeEach` function we generally do basic setup for test things like variables initialization, stubbing out external calls etc.

and 'afterEach' method works like `destroy` functions where generally we write memory releases stuff.